# Center of $GL(V)$ for $\dim V=\infty$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let's consider general linear group $GL(V)$. It's well known that if $\dim V<\infty$ then the center of this group is the subgroup of scalar operators. Is this also a case when $\dim V=\infty$?

Comment: I am not sure if this matters, but I would guess it does. What exact cardinality are you talking about? Which infinity?

Comment: Wouldn't the default finite-dimensional proof (with matrix units) be meaningful no matter the cardinality?

Comment: And what is $V$ and $GL(V)$? More precisely, are you working with vector spaces or topological vector spaces, etc.?

Comment: @MoisheKohan well by $GL(V)$ I mean invertible lineat transformations of vector space, without any additional structure

Comment: @MoisheKohan and I found out that $GL(\infty)$ is actually not the same thing